# Using OSMFilter to filter for the lack of a tag

Tags: openstreetmap, filter

I am looking into filtering the OSM data for lakes, using OSMFilter.

Lakes can be defined by the combination of tags

- **natural**=water
- **water**=lake

However, another definition would be only

- **natural**=water

If the **water** tag is not defined, it is defaulted to be a lake.

When using OSMFilter, I can easily get first definition

```
--keep="natural=water and water=lake"
```

However, I am having issues with getting the second definition, in conjuction with the first. My attempts included

```
--keep="natural=water and ( water=lake or water!=* )"
--keep="natural=water" --drop="water=* and water!=lake"
```

and various other permutations which were random stabs in the dark.

In conclusion, would there be a way to filter for the distinct lack of the tag **water**

Comment: You ever tried the famous OverpassAPI? There is a feature to find objects with a special key AND mising another key ... see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Equals_.28.3D.2C_.21.3D.29

Comment: From my understanding, I can send queries to the API, but I am limited to "10.000 queries per day or download less than 5 GB data per day."  as to not stress the system?
I am looking into creating a PostGIS database for now.

Comment: @AndrewWong These limits apply to the public Overpass API instance. You can install your own instance which doesn't have these limits.

Comment: Sometimes using `OverpassAPI` is not practical, as there may be other functionality which `osmfilter` does better.